# I do I Get the Price from CoinmarketCap API PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the price from the Coinmarketcap API, I am trying to create an application to use the price for my btc purchase:

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/

```
    {
"data": {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
    "rank": 1, 
    "circulating_supply": 17039387.0, 
    "total_supply": 17039387.0, 
    "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
    "quotes": {
        "USD": {
            "price": 8220.55, 
            "volume_24h": 5658720000.0, 
            "market_cap": 140073132803.0, 
            "percent_change_1h": 0.28, 
            "percent_change_24h": -1.18, 
            "percent_change_7d": -10.28
        }
    }, 
    "last_updated": 1526587771
}, 
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1526587666, 
    "error": null
}
```

}

Comment: How is the JSON related to your question? Is that the response you're getting from the API?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the price from the JSON using php ("price": 8220.55) as 8220.55